# Does strstr have this overload?

Tags: c, opengl

In OpenGL superbible 4th ed, an example on pg 70 reads

```
//returns space-delimited names of all extensions supported by the OpenGLDriver
const char *extensions = glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS);
if(strstr(extensions, "WGL_EXT_swap_control" != NULL))
{
   //...
}
```

Is this a type-o?  Or am I missing an `#include`?  I can't find an overload for `strstr()` to support this call.  I think it should be

```
if(strstr(extensions, "WGL_EXT_swap_control") != NULL)
{
  //...
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, obvious typo. Your code is correct. C does not support overloading.

The prototype of the function would have to be `int strstr(const char *s, int h);` for the book's code to compile, and that doesn't (as Jonathon Reinhart sort of pointed out) make a lot of sense; how do you look for an integer in a string?

**UPDATE**: There's a lesson here about the quality feel from books whose "example" code obviously won't compile.

**UPDATE 2**: As forsvarir points out, you can get a C compiler to compile this, in which case it will treat the integer resulting from the comparison as a string pointer regardless, and run `strstr()` using that. Which, on many operating systems, will immediately crash, and which will invoke undefined behavior on all systems.

Comment: Not to mention `"string-literal" != NULL` is always going to be `true`, so that code would make no sense anyway.

Comment: Why do I get error `'strstr' : none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types` from visual studio if C doesn't support overloads?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey is it being run through a C compiler or C++?

Comment: @P.Brian.Mackey sounds like you're compiling with a C++ compiler

Comment: The code would compile... it just doesn't run very well for obvious reasons: http://ideone.com/dbdWp